# RecyclerAdapter with Firebase - Where is populateViewHolder?

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I'm attempting to view database information onto my android app using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter but where I'm expecting the populateViewHolder method I'm getting two others popping up.  The code is below:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder>(

                    NoteModel.class,
                    R.layout.single_note_layout,
                    NoteViewHolder.class,
                    fNotesDatabase

            ) {
                @Override
                public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull NoteModel model) {

                }
            };

}
```

public NoteViewHolder and protected void onBindViewHolder were not expected as in the past after using FirebaseReccylerAdapater these two haven't appeared.  I was expecting:

```
protected void populateViewHolder ( NoteViewHolder viewHolder, NoteModel model, int position) {
}
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is no longer available?  I'm not sure how to go about completing the code as I've not seen it like this before.  I need to add....

```
String noteId = getRef(position).getKey();
```

....but I don't know where.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FirebaseUI [migration guide](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-3.0.md#realtime-database) is a good place to start. Essentially, you'll want to do something like this:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<NoteModel> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<>()
        .setQuery(fNotesDatabase, NoteModel.class)
        .build();

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<NoteModel, NoteViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return new NoteViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.single_note_layout, parent, false));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder holder,
                                            int position,
                                            @NonNull NoteModel model) {
                String key = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getKey();
                holder.bind(...);
            }
        };
```